# Form validation for multiple text input Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Array values in form are always a problem for form validation in CI. Now I've to input multiple values and those array values are to be stored in DB. Now **the user can keep some fields blanks by mistake** as shown below in the links:

[Input values.](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/18510/20130209-nlpu-38kb)

[Values in the array on submission.](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/18510/20130209-y3zr-36kb)

I used [this](http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-form/php-input-multiple-textbox/) tutorial to add input boxes on **+** button click. On submission the blank values will be truncated and then not null array values will added to database. I tried this using a sample program in native PHP but could not implement it in CI.

I used the following code in native PHP to insert values in DB truncating null values:

```
<?php
    include 'sql_connect.php';
    $str = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["txtSiteName"]);$i++)
    {
        $str[] = $_POST["txtSiteName"][$i];
    }
    $str = array_filter($str, function($item) {if(!is_null($item)) return $item;});
    foreach($str as $loop_str)
    {
        $arr_str[] = $loop_str;
    }
    for($k = 0; $k<count($arr_str);$k++)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO sitename (name) VALUES ('".$arr_str[$k]."')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    print_r($arr_str);
?>
```

How can I achieve this in CI ?
I tried to use callback function but the array value is not being passed to the callback function.

**EDIT:**

The below code shows my callback function :

On entering 3 urls it is called 3 times. Is that normal ?
Also my array_walk's callback function is not working. Calling a callback function inside another callback function is not possible ?

```
public function null_check()
{
    $urls = $this->input->post('link_name');
    array_walk($urls, 'prepurl');
    var_dump($urls);
}
```

prepurl function:

```
public function prepurl($item, $key)
{
    $item = "http://".$item;
}
```

Comment: Are you dunamically adding textboxes?

Comment: Can you show your `CodeIgniter` code that you have tried ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera There is nothing new. I just created a callback function `public function null_check($str)` and gave $str as an argument to it. Added multiple values but it gets only a single string in $str instead of the complete array. And in the callback function I will add the above code as in the question in native PHP excluding the DB query. But I can do that only if have the array available.

Comment: are you generating these text fields statically or dynamically

Comment: @Venkat Dynamically on button click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me but since you mentioned to validate multiple text boxes. So if your text boxes are something like this

```
<input type="text" name="txtSiteName[]" />
<input type="text" name="txtSiteName[]" />
```

then simply you can use

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtSiteName[]', 'Site Name', 'required|xss_clean');
```

to validate all the text boxes against null or empty.

**Update** (TO pass an argument in to the callback)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtSiteName[]', 'Site Name', 'callback_sitename_check[' . $this->input->post('txtSiteName') . ']');

function sitename_check($str, $sitenames) {
    // $sitenames will be your textboxe's array
}
```

The first argument is used by `CodeIgniter` by default so second argument is your parameter. Also take a look at [insert_batch()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) to insert multiple records.

Also you can do this like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtSiteName[]', 'Site Name', 'callback_sitename_check');

function sitename_check() {
    $sitenames =  $this->input->post('txtSiteName');
}
```

**Update:** (For array_walk)

```
array_walk($urls, array($this, 'prepurl'));
```

Comment: I already know this. This is not my issue. Some text boxes can be blank. Suppose user wants to add 3 values but he generates 4 text boxes by mistake then he cannot remove the extra text box. Hence if her enters 3 values and keeps the 4th text box blank then the blank value in the array will be truncated and stored in DB which will be the work of callback function.

Comment: In this case you can remove the `required` rule or use client side check to remove the empty text box before the submission.

Comment: but still people can hack if you don't do server side validation

Comment: - I removed `required` but I cannot accept null values also. -Yes I will be doing that too. I am thinking of creating a **-** button for removing the textbox.

Comment: @SheikhHeera $_POST['txtSiteName'] is throwing Undefined Variable error before submission. Also on submission no value is available. On var_dump this is shown : `string 'Array' (length=5)`

Comment: @SilentAssassin, use `$this->input->post('txtSiteName')` instead, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Undefined variable error removed but var_dump still the same.

Comment: @SilentAssassin, It should work but you can also use the `callback` without any parameters, see the update.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Okay I am getting the values. I've updated the question for another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple process of doing it

Set message like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtSiteName[]', 'Site Name', 'required|xss_clean|callback_check_array');
```

Here is callback

```
function check_array()
{
    $txtSiteName    =   $this->input->post('txtSiteName');
    $error = 0;
    foreach($txtSiteName as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!empty($value)){
            $error = $error + 1;
        }
    }       
    if($error == 0){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_array', 'All fields are empty. Please provide at leaset 1');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

When validation is successfull run this code or modify according to your requirements

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('myform');
}
else
{
    $txtSiteName    =   $this->input->post('txtSiteName');
    foreach($txtSiteName as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!empty($value)){
            $data['name']   =   $value;
            $this->mymodel->insert($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Model Method

```
function insert($data)
{
    $this-db->insert('table_name',$data);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$this->input->post('txtSiteName');` will take the complete array ?

Comment: if you have used checkboxes array than this is the same thing. if you are not sure than directly access $_POST['txtSiteName'] inside callback method.